# Multithreaded: Identifying duplicate objects

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, list

I'm trying to implement a duplicate objects finding method over a List object. Traversing through the List and finding the duplicate objects using multiple threads is the target. So far I used `ExecutorService` as follows.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < jobs; i++) {
        Runnable worker = new TaskToDo(jobs);
        executor.execute(worker);
    }
executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
}
System.out.println("Finished all threads");
```

At TaskToDo class I iterate through the loop. When a duplicate is detected the one out of them will be removed from the List. Following are the problems I faced,

1. When using multiple threads at the executor it does not result as intended. Some duplicate values are still exist in the list. But a single thread at the executor works perfectly. I tried
   `List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>())` also but same problem exists.
2. What is the best data structure that i can use for this purpose of removing duplicates for better performance ?

Google gave some results to use Concurrent structures. But difficult to figure out a correct approach to achieve this.
Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance... :)

Following is the code for iterating through the specified list object. Here actual content of the files will be compared.

```
for(int i = currentTemp; i < list.size() - 1; i++){
        if(isEqual(list.get(currentTemp), list.get(i+1))){
            synchronized (list) {
                list.remove(i + 1);
                i--;
}}}
```

Comment: Erm... Why don't you just use a `Set`?

Comment: is your list declared as volatile?  You may want to look up that keyword

Comment: Are all threads examining the entire list?  If so, why? If not, if the same object appears in a partition processed by Thread 1 and in a partition processed by Thread 2, the duplicate would never be noticed.

Comment: @fge Actual implementation of this is to identify and remove duplicate binary objects. I think it is not possible to use 'set' in this context...

Comment: @David thanks i'll look for it..

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? As long as your objects correctly implement `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` it's perfectly possible

Comment: @Eric Each all the threads are actively processing the list at the same time, but not the whole list once. b'coz the list is some what bigger.

Comment: @fge can you please guide me through. this have to compare any given image file or a data file.

Comment: How many objects do you have? Deduping with a `Set<String>` in a single-threaded way should be very fast for large n; concurrency seems like overkill here, and a `List` is _really_ not what you want.

Comment: @Louis this is not a list of strings at the real implementation. It will be either File objects or a path to a files to be compared.

Comment: What is currentTemp ? Is it the constructor parameter to the TaskToDo class ??

Comment: @charagaila: Are you comparing the actual contents of the files, or just the names?

Comment: @Pandiri `currentTemp` keeps track of the index that last thread accessed.

Comment: @LouisWasserman it is about the content sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current logic, you would have to synchronize at coarser granularity, otherwise you risk removing the wrong element.

```
for (int i = currentTemp; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
  synchronized (list) {
    if (i + 1 > list.size() && isEqual(list.get(currentTemp), list.get(i+1))) {
      list.remove(i + 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
}
```

You see, the `isEqual()` check must be inside the synchronized block to ensure atomicity of the equivalence check with the element removal. Assuming most of your concurrent processing benefit would come from asynchronous comparison of list elements using `isEqual()`, this change nullifies any benefit you sought.

Also, checking `list.size()` outside the synchronized block isn't good enough, because list elements can be removed by other threads. And unless you have a way of adjusting your list index down when elements are removed by other threads, your code will unknowingly skip checking some elements in the list. The other threads are shifting elements out from under the current thread's `for` loop.

This task would be much better implemented using an additional list to keep track of indexes that should be removed:

```
private volatile Set<Integer> indexesToRemove =
  Collections.synchronizedSet(new TreeSet<Integer>(
    new Comparator<Integer>() {
      @Override public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
        return i2.compareTo(i1); // sort descending for later element removal
      }
    }
  ));
```

The above should be declared at the same shared level as your `list`. Then the code for iterating through the list should look like this, with no synchronization required:

```
int size = list.size();
for (int i = currentTemp; i < size - 1; i++) {
  if (!indexesToRemove.contains(i + 1)) {
    if (isEqual(list.get(currentTemp), list.get(i+1))) {
      indexesToRemove.add(i + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

And finally, after you have `join()`ed the worker threads back to a single thread, do this to de-duplicate your list:

```
for (Integer i: indexesToRemove) {
  list.remove(i.intValue());
}
```

Because we used a descending-sorted TreeSet for indexesToRemove, we can simply iterate its indexes and remove each from the list.

Comment: Tried, yet the problem exists.

Comment: Ok then try what David said, make the list `volatile` so it will not be subject to thread-local caching.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a suggestion for a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. But what i want is to avoid comparing the duplicates that have been identified before in the list. Means if a duplicate is identified at the index 4 and as the iteration goes on there is no need to compare this identified duplicate with the indexes greater than 4. it is a wast. Therefore i need to update the list as soon as an duplicate is identified.

Comment: Doesn't seem like you read the code in my example. It's doing what you just said. Specifically, the line `if (!indexesToRemove.contains(i + 1)) {` avoids comparing elements that have already been identified as duplicates.

Comment: this approach worked with some changes.
`(!indexesToRemove.contains(list.get(i+1)))` and `indexesToRemove.add(list.get(i+1))` anyway thanks a lot for your time. Making the list as volatile made my code working.

Answer (score 0):

If your algorithm acts on sufficient data that you might really benefit from multiple threads, you encounter another issue that will tend to mitigate any performance benefits.  Each thread has to scan the entire list to see if the element it is working on is a duplicate, which will cause the CPU cache to keep missing as various threads compete to access different parts of the list.

This is known as [False Sharing](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/eliminate-false-sharing/217500206?pgno=1).

Even if False Sharing does not get you, you are de-duping the list in O(N^2) because for each element of the list, you re-iterate the entire list.

Instead, consider using a [Set](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/set.html) to initially collect the data.  If you cannot do that, test the performance of adding the list elements to a Set.  That should be a very efficient way to approach this problem.

Comment: The problem was with caching. Making the list as volatile solved the problem.

Comment: Marking the list as volatile also reduces the performance.  If performance is still adequate, problem solved.  If not, consider whether you can use a set from the get-go.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to dedup a large number of files, you really ought to be using a hash-based structure.  Concurrently modifying lists is dangerous, not least because indexes into the list will constantly be changing out from under you, and that's bad.

If you can use Java 8, my approach would look something like this.  Let's assume you have a `List<String> fileList`.

```
 Collection<String> deduplicatedFiles = fileList.parallelStream()
    .map(FileSystems.getDefault()::getPath) // convert strings to Paths
    .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(
       path -> {
          try {
             return ByteBuffer.wrap(Files.readAllBytes(path)),
             // read out the file contents and wrap in a ByteBuffer
             // which is a suitable key for a hash map
          } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
        },
       path -> path.toString(), // in the values, convert back to string
       (first, second) -> first) // resolve duplicates by choosing arbitrarily
    .values();
```

That's the *entire* thing: it concurrently reads all the files, hashes them (though with an unspecified hash algorithm that may not be *great*), deduplicates them, and spits out a list of files with distinct contents.

If you're using Java 7, then what I'd do would be something like this.

```
 CompletionService<Void> service = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(
     Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4));
 final ConcurrentMap<ByteBuffer, String> unique = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
 for (final String file : fileList) {
    service.submit(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        try {
          ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(Files.readAllBytes(
              FileSystem.getDefault().getPath(file)));
          unique.putIfAbsent(buffer, file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      }, null);
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
   service.take();
 }
 Collection<String> result = unique.values();
```

Comment: I'm using java 7 for this. anyway thanks for the time.

Comment: @charagaila: I've added a Java 7 implementation.  _Seriously_, using `List` like you're trying to do will get you terrible performance even if you can get it to work, which will be extremely difficult.

Comment: this executes much faster than i expected. but the final result is surprising. it contains wrong files which are not duplicates. will you please guide me through this sir. i've less experience in hashing.